# Magento: placing upsells in the product view page

Tags: php, magento

Hi I have a custom template that I want to add upsells into. I've successfully done it with related items but am having trouble with my upsells.

Here's my catalog.xml:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
...
...
<reference name="content">
...
...

<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>

<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
      <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
      <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
</block>
```

And here is my view.phtml file:

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="">
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>
</div>


<div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide" style="">
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?>
</div>
```

This seems as though it should be straight forward and work but it hasn't.

I've also remembered to create upsell products ;)

Any help most appreciated,

Billy

Comment: Turn on [template hints](http://www.topinternetguides.com/blog/2008/05/26/magento-tutorial-turning-on-template-path-hints/), this will at least let you see what blocks are being requested, even if they are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
      <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
      <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
</block>
```

inside

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

for example:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                YOUR_BLOCK_HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

[cross sell code image on view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBClg.png)

if it still it not clear to any one they can see the above image snapshot of catalog.xml file to have a clear idea where to add the code.